# mssql_query returns "Query failed"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Can't seem to find any solution to this, no matter how hard I google. I have a deadline tomorrow and need this to be resolved asap, hope that someone here can give me a hint :)

Basically I'm connecting to a MSSQL-server from PHP. Like so:

```
$db_server  = 'servername';
$db_user    = 'user';
$db_pwd = 'pwd';
$db_db  = 'dbname';

$link = mssql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pwd);

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($db_db, $link)) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

After that I try to run this code:

```
mssql_query("CREATE TABLE ##TempUserTable (UserID VARCHAR(30))", $link);
```

And then I get this error:

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
> /var/www/test.php on line 4

And yes, I've fixed the serverstuff in freetds.conf and it should be able to create a temporary table. It worked before and it's working from Eclipse / SQLExplorer.

I'm getting frustrated!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Start by using `mssql_get_last_message()` after your failed query to return the error message generated by mssql.  This will help you get a better idea of why the query is failing.

Comment: For some very strange reason the whole script started to work, without me changing a thing. Sorry to bother you all, and thanks for the tip @Jrod, I'll try that next time it fails :)